# naming conventions in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, session, naming-conventions

could any one please tell me what is the naming convention the Hibernate developers fallowing to give names for DAO calass, Sesgleton class which create Single SessionFactory and retuns Session throug a static method, hibernate mapping files etc

Comment: I think there are some typos in your question, please see if you can clarify or correct a little.

Answer (score 1):

This is highly subjective but here is what I use:

> names for DAO class

For an `Order` entity, I use `OrderDao` for the interface and `HibernateOrderDao` for the Hibernate implementation (a JPA based implementation would be `JpaOrderDao`, etc).

> class which create Single SessionFactory and retuns Session throug a static method

I use the traditional `HibernateUtil` (and you'll find many references in the Hibernate documentation, literature, etc). Here is [an example](http://jpa.ezhibernate.com/Javacode/learn.jsp?tutorial=05samplehibernateutilclassexample). There is [a more sophisticated version](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/sessionsandtransactions) in the Caveat Emptor sample app.

- hibernate mapping files

A class named `foo.bar.Foo` would be mapped by a `foo/bar/Foo.hbm.xml` file. First, this makes mappings easy to organize, to find and ease the maintenance. Second, this allows to use the strongly typed [`Configuration#addClass(Class)`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#addClass(java.lang.Class)) method (which is refactoring resistant).

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer from my rather limited experience and perspective, but I'm happy with and used to the way we do it. In general, we use an abstract class called `DatabaseHelper` that has a lot of static methods. Examples:

`DatabaseHelper.getSession()` returns a `Session`. The two methods
`DatabaseHelper.commitTransaction()` 
and
`DatabaseHelper.beginTransaction()` handle the transactions.

Beans have no naming convention, but all extend

```
public abstract class HibernateBean<T> implements Serializable
```

Like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_name")
public class TableEntry extends HibernateBean<TableEntry> {
```

The `HibernateBean` contains some methods like `getId()` to retrieve the Hibernate-generated id.